# Adding a append to an input where one already exists

Tags: html, css

This is my first post so be gentle :)

I have a form which I am updating a bit of information in multiple selections on the page.
I'm using *datepicker* to populate the box and I want to use the refresh icon to update a table with the new date info and fire off some other scripts too.
The issue is that the following code

```
<div class="control-group">
    <form name="form2" action="<?php echo editFormAction;?>">
        <label class="control-label" for="process_app_form_sent">Application Form Sent</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="date datepicker input-append">
                <input id="process_app_form_sent" name="process_app_form_sent" type="text" placeholder="Click to enter date" class="input-medium date"> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>

                <button type="submit" class="add-on input-append"><i class="icon-refresh"></i>
                </button>
                <input name="member_id" type="hidden" id="member_id" value="<?php echo $row_members['member_id']; ?>" />
                <input name="type" type="hidden" id="type" value="1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!--end form-->
</div>
```

The last box with the refresh icon in it isn't sitting right. Any ideas?

As screen grab image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxSgB.png]

Comment: Without seeing some CSS... hard to guess. Create a live example here: http://jsbin.com

Comment: Show the generated HTML instead of the PHP code.  View the source of your page and copy the relevant snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make the div outside position:relative and the button position absolute and then place it exactly where you want it using top: & left: